# Overriding generics

Tags: java

I'm failing to create this class hirerarchy that includes a generic that is comparable. What am I missing here? This throws an error.

```
public class Generics <T extends Comparable<T>> 
    extends Parent<T extends Comparable<T>> {

    ArrayList<T> ar;

    public Generics() {
        ar = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public void add(T elt){
        ar.add(elt);
    }
}
```

And the parent class is:

```
public class Parent <T extends Comparable<T>>{
    int size =0;
    public Parent(){
        size=0;
    }

    public void add(T elt){
        size++;
    }
}
```

Try "Extract Superclass"  on the following. I tried extracting the ArrayList and the add(T elt). This is on the following config:

Product Version: NetBeans IDE 7.2 (Build 201207171143)
Java: 1.7.0_07; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 23.3-b01
System: Linux version 3.2.0-30-generic running on amd64; UTF-8; en_US (nb)

```
public class Generics <T extends Comparable<T>> {

    ArrayList<T> ar;
    int size;

    public Generics() {
        ar = new ArrayList<>();
        size = 0;
    }

    public void add(T elt){
        ar.add(elt);
        size++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try out this

```
public class Generics <T extends Comparable<T>> 
    extends Parent<T> {

    ArrayList<T> ar;

    public Generics() {
        ar = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void add(T elt){
        ar.add(elt);
    }
}
```

Comment: Funny netbeans throw a stack overflow error when I tried to get the parent of the Generics class.

Comment: I"ve added the bug to the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Generics <T extends Comparable<T>> extends Parent<T> {

ArrayList<T> ar;

public Generics() {
    ar = new ArrayList<T>();
}

    public void add(T elt){
      ar.add(elt);
    }
}



public class Parent <T extends Comparable<T>>{
int size =0;
   public Parent(){
       size=0;
    }

    public void add(T elt){
      size++;
    }
}
```